# How to navigate to subpages?

Tags: next.js

From my understanding NEXT should be automatically generating the routes based on my folder structure.

I am mapping over article posts on news/index.tsx page but the urls I get are localhost3000/article-one when I need  localhost3000/news/article-one

Can anyone point out where I'm going wrong?

```
{page?.articles.map((post, i) => {
      return (
          <Link
            key={i}
            href={post?.slug.current!}
          >
            {post?.title!}
          </Link>
      )
})}
```

Folder structure:

```
- pages
  - news
    - index.tsx
    - [slug].tsx
```

EDIT
Addiction info:
Slugs are being pulled from Sanity headless CMS.
Tutorials often show routing by prepending `news/` to the slug but this in turn is prepending `news/` to all slugs

Comment: I tried this on my local pc and it is working fine. To get some clarification, when you say "the urls I get are Iocalhost:3000/article-one", are you referring to what is passed onto the href property? If so, then it could be that you just need to do something like href={\`/news/${post?.slug.current!}`}

Comment: Thanks @ytrkptl - I tried this but if I click through on a link with /news prepending the slug, next is prepending /new to all urls, I end up with news/news for example

Comment: Could you tell me what happens when you directly type "http://localhost:3000/news" in the browser address bar, and also what happens when you type "http://localhost:3000/news/article-one" directly in the address bar? Are you seeing the expected output when you directly visit these pages? If yes, then the routing is working fine but the Links are not. Can you please check and see?

Comment: Hey @ytrkptl - No issues when accessing those URL's directly, I just can't seem to navigate to them from the parent level pages!

Comment: What if you change news/index.tsx => news.tsx instead and tinker with the href? IDK might fix because of the wonky relative paths

Answer (score 1):

You can handle the dynamic routes in Next js in few ways, one of those is with `With URL Object`:

```js
{page?.articles.map((post, i) => {
      return (
          <Link
            key={i}
            href={{
              pathname: '/news/[slug]',
              query: { slug: post?.slug?.current },
            }}
          >
            <a>
              {post?.title!}
            </a>
          </Link>
      )
})}
```

Additional disclaimer. You always must add the anchor `<a>...</a>` as a child of `Link` Component.

Documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link#with-url-object

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be a really simple fix..

The nav links that were getting /news/news prepended to their slugs needed a `/` prepended before them

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you should change your code to have the correct href:

```
{page?.articles.map((post, i) => {
  return (
      <Link
        key={i}
        href={`/news${post?.slug.current!}`}
      >
        {post?.title!}
      </Link>
  )
})}
```